# Running only some of the tests after a code change

Tags: testing

Running the build can take a long time.

Why run all the tests when a given change probably only has the potential to break some of them?

You should be able to build a dependency graph of all the code that each test could possibly run, and then avoid running tests that couldn't possibly be affected.

Is there anything that does this?

Comment: Could you elaborate why you think this is useful, perhaps by giving an example? Running the unit tests shouldn't take a long time. Integration tests and other system tests may, but those are by definition touching a lot of code so you'd still run most of them on every change.

Comment: [Murphy's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Murphy's_law) - the one test you don't run is the one that would have saved you.

Answer (score 2):

[Infinitest](http://infinitest.github.io/) does this for Java. From their website:

> Each time a change is made on the source code, Infinitest runs all the tests that might fail because of these changes.

I use it as an eclipse plugin and any time I rebuild (I have it set to build on save) the project it runs any unit tests which cover the code I have modified.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio Team System has done this via [Test Impact Analysis](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff576128%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) since VS 2010.

There's walkthrough of how to set up a build environment [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms253138%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) that includes TIA.

It works with varying degrees of success depending on the structure of the codebase. For example: I don't know for sure, but I can only imagine that statically analyzing dependencies in a project that heavily depends on runtime DI isn't very easy.

In any event, for incremental builds/checkins, it makes sense to use it while daily builds run the whole suite.